# issue in deploying docker image on kubernetes through jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy a docker image through Jenkins.

`kubectl --namespace=dev apply -f k8s/dev/`

I receive this error message.

```
dev apply -f k8s/services/ error: unable to recognize "k8s/services/config-server.yaml": no matches for kind "Service" in version "v1"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! could you add some more context to your question? Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need help clarifying your question

Comment: Share your YAML scripts I'm k8s/dev/ folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your yaml file look like there is an issue in service version.

check for the service compatibility with your kubernetes version.also try applying the command the `kubectl apply -f <filename> -n <namespacename>`

you can also try : `kubectl apply -f <filename> -n <namespacename> --validate=false`